# java.util.NoSuchElementException occurs

Tags: java, android, arrays, sharedpreferences, nosuchelementexception

I have stored an integer array in a class using Shared Preference. The item is getting stored the way I want to.

But when I access it from another class, the app crashes and the Logcat shows java.util.NoSuchElementException. I am not able to understand the reason behind it.

This is the way I am storing the array.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < MyAdaptertwo.rowitems.size(); i++) {
                    str.append(MyAdaptertwo.rowitems.get(i).no).append(",");
                }
                prefs.edit().putString("no", str.toString());
```

This is the way I am retrieving it-

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    String savedno = prefs.getString("no", "");
  StringTokenizer sn = new StringTokenizer(savedno, ",");

 for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(validtotal_order); i++) {
        list_order item = new list_order(st.nextToken(),sc.nextToken(),sn.nextToken());//Error
        rowitems.add(item);
```

Logcat shows error in the line I have commented as error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must commit() your shared preference once you have added the items in it.

```
 prefs.edit().putString("no", str.toString()).commit();
```

unless you commit it, the added data won't be saved in the shared preference.

Also, better to check if it has more elements using hasMoreElements().

```
   for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(validtotal_order); i++) {
     if(sn.hasMoreElements())
       {
            list_order item = new list_order(st.nextToken(),sc.nextToken(),sn.nextToken());//Error
            rowitems.add(item);
       }
    }
```

Comment: It guess it worked. But now my elements are not getting added to the listview. List View remains empty.

Comment: That way we have just handled the exception. Now the issue is that somehow you are not getting data in sn. Just add a breakpoint and check if you are getting values from the preference.

Comment: All errors are gone! I am now getting what I wanted. Thank you for the help!

Comment: glad to hear that. happy coding :)